# How to submit for content approval/ approve content in sharpepoint using graph api

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

I currently have bunch of files stored in Sharepoint.
I've set the versioning so - that everytime user uploads a file it's set as draft and versions are set as 0.1, 0.2. Once the content is approved my version then gets updated to major version ex 1.0

I want to perform content approval process/ and also request approval all via sharepoint graph api.

I don't see any resources or endpoint to do the following.

I'm using this as of now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list-versions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the graph api cannot update SharePoint content approval yet. Every time the content approval value is updated, the system will automatically create a new version, approved status back to pending again.

You could have a try: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Similar issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a63b8952-1e0c-4f3b-917b-fcffa8bd9560/content-approval-using-graph-api-for-sharepoint?forum=appsforsharepoint